# Caching file content inside ExecuteScript processor of Apache NiFi

Tags: xml, apache-nifi, schematron

I have an *ExecuteScript* processor that does an XML flow file validation against schematron. I'd like the content of the schematron file to be cached somewhere rather than read from the disk for every flow file again and again.

What is the best option for doing this? Do I need yet another script that puts the content of the schematron into *context.stateManager* or *PutDistributedMapCache* or what?

Comment: What language you are using for ExecuteScript?

Comment: @dagget Groovy or JS, but does it matter?

Comment: In ExecuteGroovyScript processor there is a feature to handle in-memory caching. Check `Handling processor start & stop` section in https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html

Comment: @daggett Could you post this as an answer, hopefully with the sample how to handle files?

Answer (score 2):

In `groovy` script there is a possibility to declare class with static variables, so they definitely will keep status after processor started.

Additionally, to manage initialization of those static variables you could use the feature of `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor to intercept processor start and stop.

In following example I'm going to compare flow-file content to some file on disk because I'm not familiar to schematron.

```groovy
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext

class Cache {
    static String validatorText = null
}
//this function called on processor start, so you can't use flow file in it
static void onStart(ProcessContext context){
    //init cached(static) variable from file
    Cache.validatorText = new File('/path/to/validator.txt').getText('UTF-8')
    println "onStart ${context}"
}

//process flow file and compare it to `Cache.validatorText`
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def ffText = ff.read().getText("UTF-8")
assert ffText = Cache.validatorText

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

> Note: you could set `Failure strategy` = `transfer to failure`. 
>   In this case on any error (including assertion failure) flow file will be redirected to REL_FAILURE without additional code.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to answer *NO* but it seems that **it is possible**.
You are able to cache variables inside the ExecuteScript processor.

#### general idea

Using a simple script with the *ExecuteScript* processor using the *EcmaScript* engine shows that you actually are able to store state inside the processor.

```
var flowFile = session.get();

if (flowFile !== null) {
    var x = (x || 0) + 1;
    log.error('this is round: ' + x);

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
}
```

Using this script inside the processor will result in something along the lines being logged:

```
...
ExecuteScript[id=...] this is round: 3
ExecuteScript[id=...] this is round: 2
ExecuteScript[id=...] this is round: 1
```

#### updating the file at most every x time units

I [borowed](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/18245a4441406d7e4295997cba4369a27834dafd/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ValidateXml.java#L121-L125) the base code from the existing NiFi *ValidateXML* processor.

The basic idea is to update the file when

1. it is not set yet   or
2. at least x units of time have passed since last update

The following code will achieve this, whereby **SCHEMA_FILE_PATH** is the path to the schema file. In this case x is thirty seconds:

```
// type definitions
var File = Java.type("java.io.File");
var FileNotFoundException = Java.type("java.io.FileNotFoundException");
var System = Java.type("java.lang.System");

// constants
var SCHEMA_FILE_PATH = "/foo/bar"; // exchange with real path
var timeoutInMillis = 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds

// initialize
var schemaFile = schemaFile || null;
var lastUpdateMillis = lastUpdateMillis || 0;



var flowFile = session.get();

function updateSchemaFile() {
    schemaFile = new File(SCHEMA_FILE_PATH);

    if (!schemaFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Schema file not found at specified location: " + schemaFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    lastUpdateMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

if (flowFile !== null) {
    var now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    var schemaFileShouldBeUpdated = (schemaFile == null) || ((lastUpdateMillis || 0) + timeoutInMillis) < now;

    if (schemaFileShouldBeUpdated) {
        updateSchemaFile();
    }

    // TODO Do with the file whatever you want
    log.error('was file updated this round? ' + schemaFileShouldBeUpdated + '; last update millis: ' + lastUpdateMillis);

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

**DISCLAIMER**

I cannot tell if, let alone when, the variable/s may be purged. Inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/f851ed4887e503c49bd254357b703c6a66afa2fa/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-scripting-bundle/nifi-scripting-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/script/ExecuteScript.java#L162-L180) used in the ExecuteScript processor indicates that the script file is reloaded periodically. I am not sure about the consequences of that.

Also I haven't tried using one of the other ScriptingLanguage supported as I'm most familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: That's interesting. So you basically not doing anything to store the state but hoping that NiFi does that somehow and you only need to verify that it's still there.

Comment: @Shamil Well as NiFi does not seem to destroy the processor objects as long as it does not have to you, basically hold the references in memory, yes. That is not unusual however, which you'll see when you look at the linked code of the ValidateXML processor.