# NiFI: Execute a long-running process and have the results while the process still runs

Tags: apache-nifi

Hello I have a NiFi simple process group consisting on a GetTwitter connected to a `ExecuteStreamCommand`

`GetTwitter Process` ---> `ExecuteStreamCommand`

The executeStreamCommand reads the flowfile and do some analytics. Since the models that brings in memory are quite heavy, I was wondering if there was a way to keep the command alive and having the resulting flowfile without closing the execution of this one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Depends on what do you  have behind the executeStreamCommand.

Comment: @daggett Whatever it comes from the GetTwitter nifi Processor (a JSON for every tweet). But even if I do a dummy that get the flowflie and give it as output, it doesn't work untill a close the process :/

Comment: I can't understand. Who does not work? Which process?

Comment: I'll make an example: ExecuteStreamCommand is a python script that take the flowfile as input and just print on the output whatever gets from the GetTwitter process (a JSON). I don't know how to keep the "ExecuteStreamCommand" alive while flowfiles pass through it

Comment: Then your python should be running as a separate server listening for http port (for example) and taking some actions on incoming requests... In execute script it's possible to keep state of previous processed incoming files.

Comment: I guess that's the only way to do it :( Thank you @daggett

Comment: maybe this question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959352/caching-file-content-inside-executescript-processor-of-apache-nifi